# Output of optimum Linux results

Tags: bash, ubuntu, centos, vmware, suse

I am currently working on a project which involves benchmarking of Linux server systems and making recommendations on that which is best. The project involves running commands such as vmstat on the server versions of SUSE 11, Ubunutu 12.04 and Centos 7. The commands will be managed by bash scripts and a dialog menu box will be made to output the results for user ease.

However, we have now been advised that once the benchmarking results have been investigated and discussed, that we are to build a piece of software that holds the best of these. So for example, if the vmstat statistics are best on Ubunutu and the iostat is best of Centos and the boot time is quickest on SUSE, to put these all onto one system. Is this even possible however? I am not even sure how to build my own Linux OS to store these or if it is possible within the timeframe.

Surely this is not possible given that the syntax is different between the server versions themselves and the only way surely would be to ping the files across to ensure that they are on just one operating system?

Does anyone know if this is possible as I can't seem to see anything online to indicate that it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benchmarking a system as a whole is a complex task, as there are far too many variables involved. The choice of Linux distribution for a company server ends up being a political decision more than a technical one, because the optimal choice depends not only on your benchmarks, but also on maintainer familiarity with the distribution, pre-installed services and the distributions that are already installed in other servers of the company.

You cannot run Ubuntu, Centos and SUSE on the server at the same time. A system with multiple distributions installed will present you with a boot-up screen to choose one of the distros to run. This means that you will not be able to take advantage of Ubuntu's vmstat efficiency, Centos IO optimizations and SUSE boot-up time at the same time, as per your example.

The most informative benchmarks for your clients will be those that imitate your server's purpose in a real-world situation; if this is intended to be a database server then you will have to run the server on Ubuntu with the database for a couple days, then repeat on SUSE, and finally on Centos, or whatever, and design indicators to compare the three sessions on database performance. Not IO, not VM, not boot-up time.

Comment: I'll only be benchmarking them using the vmware player, I have already downloaded and installed an iso for each of them and the servers are running ok. I am currently writing bash scripts for them all and using a menu dialog box. i realise that it will be slow to use them all at once, but I am able to get them working on the vmware player at the same time. for the data itself, i wanted it to not only be output in the menu, but also in graphs. is that possible to do directly from linux servers or do the files need to be pinged to a linux desktop or even windows 7?

Comment: i have been advised to benchmark the results first through iostat, vmstat etc as well as load time and then if anything else is requested, to add that at a later stage. what i was wondering though, once the benchmarking results have been collated and added to files, is it possible to build a piece of software which can use the best elements from all 3 of the systems? i have looked online but can't seem to find anything to confirm or deny that.

Comment: You can produce the graphs directly in the linux servers using gnuplot; it handles many graphics formats and then you may choose from many ways to deliver the graphs from the servers to your clients. As for the piece of software, well, my advice is to write the software first. From your comments I presume you created one virtual server for each distribution; so are you going to write your piece of software to run in one server, or concurrently using the three of them for the same task, or in parallel, each server handling one independent task?

Comment: for the benchmarking, I will have them running separately measuring the same task, for example, check the boot time or vmstat of all of them. When I am finished though, is it possible to combine all of the best elements of the 3 servers into a new system? Can Linux from scratch or something be used?

Comment: It will be extremely difficult to combine the 3 distributions into a new 1-server system. Some years ago, I went the Linux From Scratch way on my personal computers; it was a very rewarding, educational experience. But at the time I wasn't as concerned about performance as you apparently are. You may be interested in LFS or Gentoo if you want your distribution to be tailored to your clients' particular needs. LFS/Gentoo represents a significant investment of time. Now, for ubermaximum performance you may want to run your benchmarks against the compilation flags of your LFS/Gentoo installation.

Comment: how long would you say it takes? I have until April to finish this for the client. if I use either LFS or Gentoo, would that represent a brand new system being built or does it allow elements of the established distros such as Ubuntu and Centos servers to be used? Is it possible to tailor my OS on LFS and Gentoo to have the lowest possible resource hit for each command?

Comment: It will take some weeks. Both Gentoo and LFS will allow you to choose the flags to compile every package as well as the kernel itself. Most of this time will be invested in researching the flags and understand their effects on your benchmarks; the initial installation/compilation will take less 3 days on modern servers. Keep all sources and build dirs, to rebuild against changed flags in seconds per package. The kernel itself takes 10 minutes in the initial build and some seconds per rebuild. Research flags used by each distro. You'll get the best performing, frugal system for this investment.

Comment: How long would it take to install on just one laptop for testing? A Windows 7, hp pavillion g6 laptop to be exact. With this option, would I be able to make the project completely my own in order to meet the client needs? How visible would the remnants of Ubuntu and the other distros be as I build my own OS for the client? it seems to me from what you're saying, that it is the best solution and that it is possible to combine the best elements of all 3 distros in this way. Can you recommend any good websites or books to help with this?

Comment: at this point in time, I am not concerned with the desktop versions-I only want to use lfs or gentoo to build my own server version that utilises the best performances of the three. I am not interested in desktops at this point.

Comment: Great! The laptop may take 1-2 days compiling LFS or Gentoo, text-only, no desktop packages. LFS will be completely your own project; you may even give it your own branding according to the GNU Licenses guidelines. On the other hand, the Gentoo branding is all over the installation, you will be able to wipe it provided you mention it somewhere. They both have no Ubuntu, Centos, SUSE remnants. LFS/Gentoo are more elegant solutions than a mashup of distributions. If you are satisfied with these pointers, please consider marking this as your answer. www.linuxfromscratch.org www.gentoo.org

Comment: sorry for the late reply-your advice has been helpful. I was just wondering though, I am currently researching tests to simulate stress on certain processes-do you know any commands or processes to stress the cpu, boot time and iostat/cat/vmstat to simulate how well they  act under resource pressure? I was thinking of commands such as generating prime numbers and measuring how long it takes.

Comment: There is a multitude of tests at [OpenBenchmarking](http://openbenchmarking.org) from which to choose. I haven't tried one of them myself, though. I hope you find them useful.

Comment: It says that the search functionality is disabled and the website is going through updates-can you recommend any others?

Comment: No, I havent't researched into any testsuite website, not even this one; why don't you just [browse the available test suites](http://openbenchmarking.org/suites/pts), maybe Google them afterwards? Or [Google into the website](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fopenbenchmarking.org%2Fsuites%2Fpts+vmstat&oq=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fopenbenchmarking.org%2Fsuites%2Fpts+vmstat&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.9398j0j7&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=site:http:%2F%2Fopenbenchmarking.org+memory)?

Comment: thanks I will take a look. By the way, is the dialog option only able to store 6 choices? Mine is not outputting the 7th. Is there a maximum or is it even possible to create sub dialog options within them; for example instead of options 1-6, have option 1.a, 1,b, 2.a etc?

Comment: Sorry Paul, I haven't browsed the website or performed any test, I cannot help you with that.